# is it possible to nest one form inside another in razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I put the begin/end form statement in the layout page so that I don't have to repeat it on several pages. Below's a simplified version of the code.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @RenderBody()

    <input type = "submit" name = "nextButton" value = "Next-->" />
}
```

Things are working well. Unfortunately, I have a page that has several "**Delete**" buttons. I want to generate a form for each delete button so that it can send the id of the item to delete back to the controller.

Can I do that knowing that there's already another form on top of that?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Interesting.. "I put the begin/end form statement in the layout page..." Sounds like you are one step on the path of recreating webforms. ;)

Comment: @Chris Lively: Funny??? Well with all the TagBuilder I had to deal with, I didn't know what else to do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As Mrchief says, the the HTML specs forbid nested forms.  Since MVC just generates standard HTML, you have to work withinn the framework of the spec.

Why not just create two master layouts, and use the form based one most of the time, but use one without a form when you need more control over the embedded forms.

This is the why you should really only use forms exactly where they are needed, not just everywhere.

Comment: Actually I was closer to what u just proposed. I just didn't make that page inherit from the Layout and it worked. But I had to copy/paste everything on from the layout to the page that's supposed to contain all the delete buttons. But I'm going to have another layout as you suggested.

Comment: @Richard77 - Note that you can nest *layouts* as well.  So, you can have your standard layout, sans form.  Then you can have another layout that uses the first page as it's layout, but includes the form.  Then you can choose to make either layout for your client pages.  This way, you don't have to duplicate code.

Answer (score 8):

Do note that nesting of forms is not allowed as per the [W3 specs](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html)

> Every form must be enclosed within a FORM element. There can be
> several forms in a single document, but the FORM element can't be
> nested.

There is an interseting article about caveats of nesting forms [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170420110433/http://anderwald.info/internet/nesting-form-tags-in-xhtml/).

In this case, it is better to generate a `form` for each button instead of having a single form.

ASP.Net web forms restricted you from having multiple forms on the page by using `runat=server` attribute (and the framework ensuring that only one per page was allowed). MVC `forms` are pure HTML so you can have multiple of them.